# Angular not rendering the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to render the contacts list after retrieving it thru rdflib.js. It is loading properly and saving it in the list inside the scope.

It does recognize the number of items in the list, but I am not able to render the values since the $scope doesn't update, it seems like I am calling $scope.apply() in the wrong place. It seems it is because I call it outside angular, but I am deliberately calling it inside the function that is outside angular context (nowOrWhenFetched), so not making sense for me. any help?

```
$scope.load = function () {
    //$scope.getContactsList();
    var g = $rdf.graph();
    var f = $rdf.fetcher(g);

    f.nowOrWhenFetched($scope.path + '*',undefined,function(){

    var DC = $rdf.Namespace('http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/');
    var RDF = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#');
    var LDP = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/ns/ldp#');
    //var myOntology = $rdf.Namespace('http://user.pds.org/ontology/'); 
    var VCARD = $rdf.Namespace('http://www.w3.org/2006/vcard/ns#');

    var evs = g.statementsMatching(undefined, RDF('type'), VCARD('Individual'));
    if (evs != undefined) {
        for (var e in evs) {
            var id = evs[e]['subject']['value'];
            var fullname = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('fn'))['object']['value'];
            var email = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('hasEmail'))['object']['value'];
            var phone = g.anyStatementMatching(evs[e]['subject'], VCARD('hasTelephone'))['object']['value'];

            var contact = {
                id: id.slice(id.length-1),
                Name: fullname,
                Email: email,
                Phone: phone 
            };

            $scope.contacts.push(contact);
        }

    }

    $scope.apply();

    });

};
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you defined $scope.contacts as an array?  Just want to be sure you're not calling .push on undefined?

Comment: Yes, $scope.contacts = []; is defined inside the controller where this $scope.load() is defined.

Comment: try $scope.$apply(function(){...}); pattern. What's $scope.apply function?

Comment: @lujcon first way was rendering number of rows as much as the length of the list. This way you suggested doesnt render anything

Comment: There is nothing like $scope.apply() in angular. The function is named $apply and instead calling it at the end of your code you should wrap your code with this function. This way angular will call $digest and in case of errors - throw them to the console. http://jsfiddle.net/je0beag4/